# Google App Engine with Eclipse using Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gwt-rpc

I have used JDO for storing my data on Google Datastore for an application written in Java with Eclipse using GWT. In which it makes GWT RPC call for following service functions:

```
    public String greetServer(String mail,String pass) 
{
    User e;
    PersistenceManager pm1 =JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory().getPersistenceManager();
    try
    {
        e = pm1.getObjectById(User.class, mail);
    }finally {
        pm1.close();
    }
    if(e.getPassword()==pass)
    {
    return "valid";
    }
    else
        return "invalid";

}
public String UserRegister(String data[])
{

    PersistenceManager pm2 = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory().getPersistenceManager();
     Date d1=new Date();
     User u1=new User(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],d1);


    try {
        pm2.makePersistent(u1);
    } finally {
        pm2.close();
    }
    return "done";
}
```

and I have been getting following error in logs

javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.google.gwt.sample.login.client.GreetingService.UserRegister(java.lang.String[])' threw an unexpected exception: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: No PersistenceManagerFactory configurable via properties resource "" or no named PMF or persistence unit named "" found.

Please help as soon as possible.